# FORMAT command isn't taking the Label (DVD-RW)

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I get a Disc's label using `vol`, When I pipe that to `FORMAT` for when it asks:

```
Enter current volume label for drive D:
```

This happens:

```
Erasing [FD11SRC]...

The type of the file system is RAW.
The new file system is UDF.
Enter current volume label for drive D: An incorrect volume label was entered fo
r this drive.
```

The `Erasing [FD11SRC]...` is from my code.
Why does it say that `FD11SRC` is incorrect?
When I *type* in `FD11SRC` when it asks me to, It takes it and formats the disc!
But when I *pipe* in `FD11SRC` it treats it as wrong!

Code:

```
@echo off
D:
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol') do (
   set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
set vol=%vol: =%
echo Erasing [%vol%]...
title Erasing...
echo.
C:
(
echo %vol%
echo y
echo y
) | format D: /FS:UDF /V:DOS_STUFF
cls
echo Erased [%vol%].
echo Copying files to [DOS_STUFF].
title Copying files to [DOS_STUFF].
echo.
xcopy /e /h /y copy\*.* D:\
```

Comment: Why not use the `/V` switch with an environment variable?  I would not assume that `format.com` even supports standard input from the pipe.

Comment: Wait, DVD-RW? What version of `format` supports erasing a rewritable optical disc?

Comment: It is simpler to use `diskpart` (with the `/s` option to specify a script).

Comment: @BaconBits Win7 does

Answer (score 0):

`vol` returns serial number plus label, plus a series of strings in addition.

There seems no option to return the raw label.

Volume labels, on the contrary, are limited to 11 characters which is definitely shorter than the `vol` output's first line in any European languages.

Comment: I used a `FOR` to get the label only.

Comment: It might help to add the exact command you tried in order to help finding it out.